# Coordinate Plot for Clustering Visualitzation/Analysis

Tags: r, plot, graph, cluster-analysis, hclust

I have a dataset (already scaled) consisting of a total of 8 columns:

- first column indicating the assigned cluster each observation belongs,
- and, 7 dependent variables (each in a different column).

I would like to develop a Clustering Visualization through a Coordinate Plot in R, just like shown in the following blog (http://blog.datascienceheroes.com/short-lesson-on-cluster-analysis/).

Could anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Many options. You could do

```
library(GGally)
ggparcoord(aggregate(mtcars, list(as.factor(cutree(hclust(dist(mtcars)), k = 4))), mean), columns=-1, groupColumn=1)
```

or

```
library(parcoords)
parcoords(
  aggregate(mtcars, list(cutree(hclust(dist(mtcars)), k = 4)), mean),
  color = list( colorScale = htmlwidgets::JS('d3.scale.category10()'), colorBy = "Group.1")
)
parcoords(
  transform(mtcars, cluster = cutree(hclust(dist(mtcars)), k = 4)),
  color = list( colorScale = htmlwidgets::JS('d3.scale.category10()'), colorBy = "cluster")
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the code for the function you need(`plot_clus_coord`) [here](https://github.com/pablo14/clusplus/blob/master/R/clusplus.R).